# Sheets Script to Clear cell only when both target cells are cleared

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I got a script thanks to help of another user Marios but I required a tweak and was asked to create a new post.

The original script

```
function onEdit(e){

  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var dateTime = 4;
  var targetColumn = 9;
  var startRow = 19;
  var ws = "Tracking Sheet";
  var as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  
  if(col === targetColumn && row >= startRow && as.getName() === ws ) 
     {
       let range = as.getRange(row,dateTime); 
       e.range.getValue() == '' ?  range.setValue('') : range.setValue(new Date());
     }
}
```

I tried to modify by adding an else statement but was unsucessful.

This works great for in all aspects but only for one targetColumn and I would like to have 2 targetColumns and then the script would only clear the dateTime cell if both of the targetColumns are seen to be empty or cleared.

```
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var dateTime = 4;
  var targetColumn = 9;
  var targetColumn = 11;
  var startRow = 19;
```

Any help or a modification to the current script would be most welcomed,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

- You assigned two different values to the same variable:

  ```
  var targetColumn = 9;
  var targetColumn = 11;
  ```

  but that simply means `targetColumn` will only have the last value assigned to it, which is `11`.
- My approach would be to put the target columns into an array and then check whether both of them are empty before you delete the date value from the desired cell.

### Solution:

```
function onEdit(e){

  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var dateTime = 4;
  var targetColumns = [9,11];
  var startRow = 19;
  var ws = "Tracking Sheet";
  var as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  
  if(targetColumns.includes(col) && row >= startRow && as.getName() === ws ) 
     {
       let range = as.getRange(row,dateTime); 
       let t1 = as.getRange(row,targetColumns[0]).getValue();
       let t2 = as.getRange(row,targetColumns[1]).getValue();
       t1 == '' && t2 == '' ?
       range.setValue('') : 
       range.setValue(new Date());
     }
}
```

Comment: Yet again speedy resposne and does what I need.

Love this site, always helpful people when you have an issue.

Comment: @JasonWatts Glad it was helpful to you :)